# Destructuring in JavaScript during a John Smilga project

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I am working on a John Smilga project, Comfy Store. I am attempting to destructure data from an API with the following code

```
let store = getStorageItem('store');
const setupStore = (products) => {
    store = products.map((product) => {
        const {
            id, 
            fields: { featured, name, price, company, colors, image:img },} = product;
        const image = img[0].thumbnails.large.url;
        return { id, featured, name, price, company, colors, image };
        
    });
    
    setStorageItem('store', store);
};
console.log(store);
```

When a console.log store this ids what I get[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWr7E.png)

Why I am getting all the properties I am asking for EXCEPT the company one?
And how to I get the Company one to show in the console?

This is what the data looks like[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G04Z.png)

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: I added the following lines of code ```const companyGet = fields[0]
        return { id, featured, name, price, companyGet, colors, image };``` which did not work. Am I understanding you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

By the code you provided it's hard to tell where and how you call setupStore function at all. Maybe you override values somewhere in-between

The destructuring in this example should work normally, but this code is not enough to identify the issue

Comment: If you are not giving a solution, or if you are asking for more information, write a comment instead. Not an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @nacho, I would but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet :) sorry

Answer (score -1):

You are returning an array of obj from that API, using map function,
if you need the first one try getting the first one with [0]

Comment: I added the following lines of code const companyGet = fields[0]         return { id, featured, name, price, companyGet, colors, image }; which did not work. Am I understanding you correctly? Also why is it working for the other properties?

Comment: hello , you should do like this:   let {id,   fields: { featured, name, price, company, colors, image:img },} = product[0];